# Laplace Transform working out

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

So I have a problem (two problems, actually) that a friend helped me out with, I'm able to work out the components of this problem but get lost when I have to bring it all together... so what I have is this

$f(t)=t^{2}e^{-2t}+e^{-t}\cos(3t)+5$

Simple enough. I got:

$$\mathcal{L}[t^2]=\frac{2}{s^2}$$

$$\mathcal{L}[e^{-2t}]=\frac{1}{s+2}$$

$$\mathcal{L}[e^{-t}]=\frac{1}{s+1}$$

$$\mathcal{L}[\cos(3t)]=\frac{s}{s^2+9}$$

$$\mathcal{L}[5]=\frac{5}{s}$$

Now the problem is bringing it all together... Apparently,

$$\mathcal{L}[t^2e^{-2t}]=\frac{2}{(s+2)^2}$$

And

$$\mathcal{L}[e^{-t}\cos(3t)]=\frac{s}{(s+1)^2+9}$$

and I just don't seem to get why...? how do you bring those guys together like that? whats the reason behind it?

the other problem is much simpler and I'm sure I have the correct answer... it is:

$$t^3-5\cos(5t)$$

I get:

$$\mathcal{L}[t^3]=\frac{6}{s^4}$$

And

$$\mathcal{L}[5\cos(5t)]=\frac{s}{s^2+25}$$

which together is supposedly,

$$\mathcal{L}[t^3-5\cos(5t)]=\frac{6}{s^4}-\frac{5s}{s^2-25}$$

Is it correct? Any help at all is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sorry. Your answer for one part is wrong. We have: $$L\left[e^{-t} \cos (3t)\right]=\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+9}$$

Also, $$L \left[5\cos (5t)\right] = \frac{5s}{s^2+25}$$ a typo perhaps?

Note that if $f(t) $ has the transform $F(s) $, then $$L\left[e^{at} f(t) \right] = F(s-a) $$ This is called the First Shifting Theorem.

Comment: yeh? how do you get that??

and can I ask... what are some good resources for this stuff?? my teachers are REALLY bad.... :(((

Comment: Hope you find [this tutorial](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplaceIntro.aspx) useful.

Comment: I'll look at it in the morning... it's 1am here. thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall the [Laplace transform shift property](https://www.intmath.com/laplace-transformation/3-properties.php),
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(e^{-at}f(t) \right)(s)=\mathcal{L}f(s+a).
$$ It applies to your cases.